# Tableau doesn't display tables after odbc connection in clickhouse?

Tags: odbc, tableau-api, clickhouse

I have tableau 2019.4 installed and even after successful odbc connection, no tables are displayed. I have tried both ANSI and Unicode drivers but no tables are shown even when database is connected.

Comment: I suspect should be displayed *databases* not *tables*. Didn't be displayed any databases even *system*?

Comment: @vladimir yes database is shown but table is not shown. This issue persists only on tableau desktop, not server.

Comment: just check: did you follow a way like described here https://www.altinity.com/blog/2018/7/19/tableau-with-clickhouse?